# Hacer visibles elementos que no estan marcadas como visibles en el SceneBuilder en un proyecto Java Standar

Tags: java, scenebuilder

Estoy realizando un proyecto de java estandar utilizando interfaces hechas en SceneBuilder, la cosa es que al iniciar sesion el administrador y al darle al boton de agregar usuario, quiero que se muestren campos para ingresar los datos, pero estos campos los tengo como visible= false en el fxml del SceneBuilder. Al darle al boton no se muestra ningun elemento de los que deberian aparecer. A continuacion comparto las clases relevantes del codigo
la clase controlador:

```
package Controlador;
import Modelo.GestionUsuarios;
import Vista.administradorVista;
import Vista.iniciarSesionVista;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
public class administradorControlador implements Initializable {
    private GestionUsuarios gestorUsuarios;
    private iniciarSesionVista vista;
    private administradorVista adminVista;
    private Stage stage;
    private boolean initialized = false;
    // Otros métodos del controlador
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setVista(iniciarSesionVista vista) {
        this.vista = vista;
    }
    public void setAdminVista(administradorVista adminVista) {
        this.adminVista = adminVista;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAgregar() {
        System.out.println("Botón Agregar Usuario presionado");
        if (adminVista != null) {
            adminVista.mostrarElementosAgregarUsuario(true);
        } else {
            System.err.println("La vista es nula.");
        }
    }


    private void cerrarVentana() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.close();
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handleCentrosCuidadoAnimal() {
        // Lógica para el botón centrosCuidadoAnimal
    }
    // Otros métodos para manejar acciones de los botones
    public void mostrarVista() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Vista/resources/administradorVista.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            administradorControlador controlador = loader.getController();
            controlador.setGestorUsuarios(gestorUsuarios);
            controlador.setAdminVista(adminVista);

            if (stage == null) {
                Stage newStage = new Stage();
                newStage.setTitle("Administrador.");
                newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                newStage.show();
                stage = newStage;  // Almacena la referencia al nuevo escenario
            } else {
                // Si ya existe, simplemente trae la ventana al frente
                stage.toFront();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public GestionUsuarios getGestorUsuarios() {
        return gestorUsuarios;
    }

    public void setGestorUsuarios(GestionUsuarios gestorUsuarios) {
        this.gestorUsuarios = gestorUsuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        this.initialized = true;
    }
}
```

La clase vista:

```
package Vista;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import Controlador.administradorControlador;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class administradorVista {
    @FXML
    public Button agregarBtn; // boton para mostrar los campos para agregar un nuevo usuario
    @FXML
    public Button centrosCuidadoAnimalBtn; // boton para mostrar el modulo de centros de cuidado animal
    @FXML
    public Button modificarDatosUsuarioBtn; //boton para mostrar los campos para modificar un usuario;
    @FXML
    public Button eliminarBtn; // boton para mostrar los campos para eliminar un usuario.
    @FXML
    public Button identificacionMascotasBtn;
    @FXML
    public Button controlAlertasBtn; // boton para mostrar la interfaz del modulo de alertas
    @FXML
    public Button agregarUsuarioBtn=new Button(); // boton para agregar un usuario a la lista de usuarios del programa
    @FXML
    public Button modificarUsuarioBtn=new Button(); // boton para modificar un usuario de la lista de usuarios
    @FXML
    public Button eliminarUsuarioBtn=new Button(); // boton para eliminar un usuario de la lista de usuarios del programa
    @FXML
    public Button modificarBtn=new Button(); // boton para ver si el usuario ingresado puede ser modificado.
    @FXML
    public TextField cedulaUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField nombreUsuario =new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField direccionUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField telefonoUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField correoElectronicoUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField claveUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public TextField confirmarClaveUsuario=new TextField();
    @FXML
    public Label agregarUsuarioTexto=new Label();
    @FXML
    public Label modificarUsuarioTxt=new Label();
    @FXML
    public Label modificarTxt=new Label();
    @FXML
    public Label eliminarUsuarioTxt=new Label();
    @FXML
    public SplitMenuButton rolUsuario = new SplitMenuButton();
    @FXML
    public MenuItem personalCGAItem= new MenuItem();
    @FXML
    public MenuItem duenioEstablecimientoItem= new MenuItem();
    @FXML
    public MenuItem duenioMascotaItem= new MenuItem();
    @FXML
    public MenuItem administradorItem= new MenuItem();
    private Stage stage;
    private administradorControlador controlador;
    private iniciarSesionVista vistaIniciarSesion;



    public void mostrarElementosAgregarUsuario(boolean mostrar) {
        System.out.println("Mostrando elementos para agregar usuario: " + mostrar);

        if (cedulaUsuario != null) {
            cedulaUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
            System.out.println("Visibilidad de cedulaUsuario: " + cedulaUsuario.isVisible());
        }
        if (nombreUsuario != null) {
            nombreUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            nombreUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
            System.out.println("Visibilidad de nombreUsuario: " + nombreUsuario.isVisible());
        }
        if (direccionUsuario != null) {
            direccionUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            direccionUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }

        if (telefonoUsuario != null) {
            telefonoUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            telefonoUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (correoElectronicoUsuario != null) {
            correoElectronicoUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            correoElectronicoUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (claveUsuario != null) {
            claveUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            claveUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (confirmarClaveUsuario != null) {
            confirmarClaveUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            confirmarClaveUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (agregarUsuarioTexto != null) {
            agregarUsuarioTexto.setManaged(mostrar);
            agregarUsuarioTexto.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (rolUsuario != null) {
            rolUsuario.setManaged(mostrar);
            rolUsuario.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (personalCGAItem != null) {
            personalCGAItem.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (duenioEstablecimientoItem != null) {
            duenioEstablecimientoItem.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (duenioMascotaItem != null) {
            duenioMascotaItem.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (administradorItem != null) {
            administradorItem.setVisible(mostrar);
        }
        if (agregarUsuarioBtn != null) {
            agregarUsuarioBtn.setManaged(mostrar);
            agregarUsuarioBtn.setVisible(mostrar);
            System.out.println("Visibilidad de agregarUsuarioBtn: " + agregarUsuarioBtn.isVisible());
            // Si la escena es diferente de null, solicitar una actualización de diseño
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                Scene scene = agregarUsuarioBtn.getScene();
                if (scene != null) {
                    scene.getRoot().requestLayout();
                }
            });
        }
        if (controlador != null) {
            controlador.setAdminVista(this);
        }
        actualizarInterfazGrafica();
    }
    private void actualizarInterfazGrafica() {
        if (agregarUsuarioBtn != null) {
            Scene scene = agregarUsuarioBtn.getScene();
            if (scene != null) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    scene.getRoot().requestLayout();
                });
            }
        }
    }
    @FXML
    public void handlePersonalCGAItem() {
        System.out.println("Personal CGA seleccionado");
        // Lógica para el menú desplegable de roles (pe}rsonalCGAItem)
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleDuenioEstablecimientoItem() {
        System.out.println("Dueño de Establecimiento seleccionado");
        // Lógica para el menú desplegable de roles (duenioEstablecimientoItem)
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleDuenioMascotaItem() {
        System.out.println("Dueño de Mascota seleccionado");
        // Lógica para el menú desplegable de roles (duenioMascotaItem)
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleAdministradorItem() {
        System.out.println("Administrador seleccionado");
        // Lógica para el menú desplegable de roles (administradorItem)
    }
    public Scene getScene() {
        if (agregarBtn != null) {
            return agregarBtn.getScene();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public void cerrarVentana() {
        if (stage != null) {
            stage.close();
        }
    }
    public administradorControlador getControlador() {
        return controlador;
    }

    public void setControlador(administradorControlador controlador) {
        this.controlador = controlador;
    }
    public void setVistaIniciarSesion(iniciarSesionVista vistaIniciarSesion) {
        this.vistaIniciarSesion = vistaIniciarSesion;
    }
}
```

El Fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitMenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="544.0" prefWidth="996.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controlador.administradorControlador">
   <top>
      <HBox prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #B4D3E8;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
               <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="67.0" prefWidth="951.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;" text="Administrador">
                  <font>
                     <Font name="Roboto Light" size="40.0" />
                  </font>
               </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </top>
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ScrollPane prefHeight="473.0" prefWidth="395.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="389.0" style="-fx-background-color: #B5EECD;">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="agregarBtn" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAgregar" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Agregar Usuario">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="centrosCuidadoAnimalBtn" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="293.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Modulo Centros de Cuidado Animal">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="modificarDatosUsuarioBtn" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Modificar datos de Usuario">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="eliminarBtn" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="127.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Eliminar Usuario">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="controlAlertasBtn" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Módulo de Control de Alertas">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button fx:id="identificacionMascotasBtn" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="237.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" text="Módulo de Identificación de Mascotas">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="179.0" prefWidth="0.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="cedulaUsuario" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="271.0" promptText="Cédula" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="nombreUsuario" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="97.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="273.0" promptText="Nombre Completo" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false" >
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="direccionUsuario" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="144.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="271.0" promptText="Dirección" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="telefonoUsuario" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="191.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="265.0" promptText="Teléfono" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="correoElectronicoUsuario" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="267.0" promptText="Correo Electronico" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <SplitMenuButton fx:id="rolUsuario" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="285.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="267.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" text="Elija el Rol del usuario: " visible="false">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="personalCGAItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Personal CGA" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="duenioEstablecimientoItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Dueños de Establecimientos de Mascotas" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="duenioMascotaItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Dueños de Mascotas" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="administradorItem" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Administrador" />
               </items>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </SplitMenuButton>
            <TextField fx:id="claveUsuario" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="332.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="269.0" promptText="Contraseña" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <TextField fx:id="confirmarClaveUsuario" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="379.0" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="272.0" promptText="Confirmar Contraseña" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Button fx:id="agregarUsuarioBtn" layoutX="448.0" layoutY="420.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" text="Añadir Usuario" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label fx:id="agregarUsuarioTexto" layoutX="5.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="585.0" text="Ingrese a continuacion los datos del usuario que desea agregar:" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="21.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button fx:id="modificarUsuarioBtn" layoutX="419.0" layoutY="422.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" text="Modificar Usuario" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="eliminarUsuarioBtn" layoutX="428.0" layoutY="422.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" text="Eliminar Usuario" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label fx:id="modificarUsuarioTxt" layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="585.0" text="Ingrese el numero de cedula del usuario que desea modificar:" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="21.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="modificarTxt" layoutX="5.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="465.0" text="Modifique los datos del usuario: " visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="29.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button fx:id="modificarBtn" layoutX="492.0" layoutY="424.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #B5EECD; -fx-border-color: #B4D3E8; -fx-border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;" text="Modificar" visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Label fx:id="eliminarUsuarioTxt" layoutX="10.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="597.0" text="Ingrese el numero de cedula del usuario que desea eliminar: " visible="false">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Roboto Light" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

El problema es que los elementos visuales cuyo estado visible=false, que deberian aparecer al darle al boton agregarBtn no aparecen, en consola si se imprimen los mensajes de depuracion pero el setVisible no funciona o la vista no recibe este comando. Por que no cambian su estado, de igual forma intente hacer visible a un elemento de estos y ocultarlo al aplastar el boton y tampoco pude. Necesito ayuda para poder mostrar ya los elementos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con JavaFx debes saber que las ejecuciones se hacen en hilos distintos siendo el primero de JavaSE y el otro es el hilo grafico javaFX, por lo tanto cada vez que quieras modificar una propiedad de cualquier nodo debes hacer lo siguiente.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
        boton.setVisible(true); // o false
    });
```